# Change Font Family of Everything Including Captions in revtex4-1

Tags: fonts, captions, revtex, fontfamily

I have been having trouble changing the font of the revtex4-1 document class. Specifically, the following example changes the font of everything except the captions.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, reprint,amsmath,amssymb, aps]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{cmbright}
\fontfamily{cmss}
%\usepackage[format=plain,justification=justified]{caption}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\begin{document}        
\title{The Title}

\author{The Author}

\maketitle

\section{Heading}
Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. 

\begin{figure}
    Insert figure here.
    \caption{Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The caption package will change the font automatically fix the font of captions, however I have heard that it is incompatible with revtex4-1. When I uncomment the fifth line in the snippet above, the caption text is no longer justified.

Is there something I'm missing to change the font of captions in revtex4-1?

Thanks,
-Bentley

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should redefine `\rmdefault`, rather than doing `\fontfamily{cmss}`.

I added also `\sfdefault` and another line to avoid a spurious warning.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, reprint,amsmath,amssymb, aps]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{cmbright}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{cmss}{m}{it}{<->ssub*cmss/m/sl}{}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{cmss}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{cmss}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\begin{document}

\title{The Title}

\author{The Author}

\maketitle

\section{Heading}

Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is
some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some
text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text.
Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is
some text.

\begin{figure}
Insert figure here.

\caption{Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some
text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text.
Here is some text. Here is some text.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much this works perfectly! What does the DeclareFontShape line do?

Comment: @Yharooer The substitution rule in `ot1cmss.fd` has `sub` instead of `ssub`: the line I added uses the latter (silent substitution), so you don't get an annoying warning at each run.